# Running symfony encore to start using vue on symfony 5.3

Tags: javascript, webpack, yarnpkg

I'm trying to start using VueJs on my Symfony project using encore and I get this error.

> yarn run v1.22.5
> warning ........\package.json: No license field
> \node_modules.bin\encore dev
> error Command failed with exit code 1.
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I'm using yarn this is my package.json

```js
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@symfony/stimulus-bridge": "^2.0.0",
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^1.0.0",
        "core-js": "^3.0.0",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
        "stimulus": "^2.0.0",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to share code or errors.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that before

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
rm -rf vendor/
rm composer.lock
rm -rf node_modules
composer install
php bin/console cache:clear
yarn install
yarn run dev
```

Comment: I tried it and now I got a yarn error I think